# Which music players use the SoundMenu?

Tags: music, indicator-sound

I'm not looking for recommendations on what music player I should use. I would simply like to know which Music players use Ubuntu's new sound menu. The only two I know of for sure are Banshee and Rhythmbox. Maybe Amarok does too? Are there any outside of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Players need to have [MPRIS](http://www.mpris.org/) support and register themselves on the sound menu as [described](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu#Music%20player%20integration) on the sound menu specification to place their controls in it. Currently Rhythmbox, Amarok and Banshee (via the plugin shipped in the `banshee-extension-soundmenu` package in Maverick) work in Maverick, [Xnoise](http://groups.google.com/group/xnoise/browse_thread/thread/1818498fa8b67133?hl=en) and [mpd](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/how-to-add-mpd-to-ubuntu-sound-menu.html) have plugins / versions you can install externally, and work is underway to add support in [Exaile](https://bugs.launchpad.net/exaile/+bug/618483) and [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=149#c14).

Answer (score 3):

By default it's Banshee and Rhythmbox as you said but Banshee needs a plugin to work with it. I'm sure there's others that work but they might need a plugin. Amarok and Xnoise seem to work as well.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu

[image]